# Use SPSiteDataQuery to get all site collection lists having same column name

Tags: sharepoint-server, query

I have one site collection that is `RootSite`. Two sub sites that are `subSite1` and `subSite2`.

`subSite1` has list `EMP_info` with columns `Title` and `Dept`.

`subSite2` has list `DEPT_info` with columns `Title` and `Dept_ID`.

I want to show list `EMP_info` and `DEPT_info` on `RootSite` in a Visual Web Part.

I implemented it by using `SPSiteDataQuery`, writing two separate queries. But how is it possible to write it using a single query?

If there are 1000 sub sites and 1000 lists with same column name, then how it is possible to get that 1000 list using a single query?

Comment: Mohsin - add a tag specifying the SharePoint Version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we should we able to pull all the list under one sitecollection using only one query.

For Instance,

If all the list that you are looking to pull the data are custom List then set

```
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"100\" MaxListLimit=\"0\" />";
```

The threshold of how many list's can be returned. 
It has been answered [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/10d8c18e-2686-4543-b2eb-dd937148eb43/limitations-of-spsitedataquery). By default the Limit is 1000, but if you mention 0, then there will be no limit set, and thus all the lists will be return.

Set the web scope to Site Collection

```
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
```

Since `SubSite1` and `SubSite2` falls under `RootSite`, it should be able to pull all the list under the site collection.

Follow this msdn [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) for more insights.

Comment: If all list having same column name?